# Writing function that checks if lists have the same elements

Tags: python

**EDIT:** This is a learning exercise that is explicitly about lists and functions. Converting the lists to sets is thus not allowed.

I need to write a function `def sameSet(a,b)` that checks whether two lists have the same elements in some order, ignoring duplicates. For example, the two lists [1, 4, 9, 16, 9, 7, 4, 9, 11] and [11, 11, 7, 9, 16, 4, 1] would be considered equal.

Here's what I did. I first defined a helper function `def contained(list1, list2)` that checks if list 1 is contained in list 2, by incrementing a counter whenever an element of list 1 is in list 2. Then in the end, if the counter equals the length of list 1, I set the Boolean variable `same` to `True`, because that means every element in list 1 is also in list 2.

```
    def main():
        list1 = [1, 4, 9, 16, 9, 7, 4, 9, 11, 11]
        list2 = [11, 11, 7, 9, 16, 4, 1]

    def sameSet(list1, list2):
        contained(list1, list2)
        contained(list2, list1)


    def contained(list1, list2):

        same = False
        count = 0

        for element in list1:
            if element in list2:
                count = count + 1
            else:
                count = count

        if count == len(list1):
            same = True

        return same

    main()
```

I'm not sure what to write for the function `sameSet`. I want it to check if the Boolean variable `same` is set to `True` for the both inclusions (i.e. if list1 is in list2, and if list2 is in list1, meaning they are equal). But I don't know how to implement this into Python so that the program works correctly. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I refactored your code to make it a little more pythonic, and ran a couple of tests... along with some printed output to check quickly.

Your contained function also works with the SameSet function below, but it isn't as efficient. It has unnecessary variables and such...

```
def sameSet(list1, list2):
        if contained(list1, list2) and contained(list2, list1):
                print("the same!!")    
        else:
            print("not the same")


def contained(list1, list2):

    for element in list1:
        if element not in list2:
           return False

    return True

def main():
    # this prints "the same"
    sameSet([1, 4, 9, 16, 9, 7, 4, 9, 11, 11], [11, 11, 7, 9, 16, 4, 1])
    # this prints "not the same"
    sameSet([1, 4, 9, 16, 9, 7, 4, 9, 11, 11], [11, 11, 7, 9, 16, 4,12345])


if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: What should I write under the main header then?

Comment: i made a refactor to keep the main() function, it is not strictly necessary to have a main() in a python script.

Answer (score 3):

Convert the two lists to sets, and compare the sets

```
>>> list1 = [1, 4, 9, 16, 9, 7, 4, 9, 11] 
>>> list2 =  [11, 11, 7, 9, 16, 4, 1]
>>> set(list1) == set(list2)
True
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but the problem is about lists explicitly (that is actually the point). I'm studying this book and sets hasn't been mentioned yet.

Comment: @Kamil: you might want to update your question with that fact, that this is a learning exercise for working with lists without using sets.

Answer (score 1):

Considering the new **edit**:

To check whether a list `l1` is equal (from an aspect of similar contents) to a list `l2` without using `set` you can use the handy built-in [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) function.

You need to make sure that you check if the values of the ***larger*** list are **all** in the smaller one or else you won't really get what you want.

As a small demonstration:

```
l1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
l2 = [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2]

print(all(i in l1 for i in l2))  # True

l2.append(5)  # l2 = [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 5]
print(all(i in l1 for i in l2))  # False
```

But if you make the mistake of checking whether the contents of the smaller list `l1` are in the larger list `l2` after `l2.append(5)` has been performed, you'll be disappointed:

```
print(all(i in l2 for i in l1)) # Prints True :^)
```

---

To make this into a function --and essentially re-invent the `all()` wheel-- without doing anything 'fancy' you could do something like this:

```
def sameSet(a, b):
    # l1 is the large list, l2 the small list
    l1, l2 = (a, b) if len(a) > len(b) else (b, a)
    for val in l1:
        if val not in l2:
            return False
    return True
```

Which does the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Without changing anything in your code i would just put in the sameset function:

```
if contained(list1,list2)==True and contained(list2,list1)==True:
      return True
else:
      return False
```

Comment: actually `if contained(list1,list2) and contained(list2,list1):` would be enough, since they are boolean values

Answer (score 0):

Use dict and zip

```
def unq(l):
    return sorted(x for x in dict(zip(l,l)))

stat = unq(l1) == unq(l2)
```

so build a dictionary of each list and sort the list of keys, then just compare the 2 results, where stat is a boolean (True or False)